# Pygame snake game TypeError: randomize_position() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to learn pygame so I am looking off a tutorial of a guy that made snake in pygame and I did it exactly as he did but it doesn't work. Towards the end I get this error:
TypeError: randomize_position() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
heres where the error takes place:

```
food.randomize_position()
```

and heres the full code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random


class snake(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [((SCREEN_WIDTH / 2), (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2))]
        self.direction = random.choice([UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT])
        self.color = (17, 24, 47)

    def get_head_position(self):
        return self.positions[0]

    def turn(self, point):
        if self.length > 1 and (point[0] * -1, point[1] * -1) == self.direction:
            return
        else:
            self.direction = point

    def move(self):
        cur = self.get_head_position()
        x, y = self.direction
        new = (((cur[0] + (x * GRIDSIZE)) % SCREEN_WIDTH), (cur[1] + (y * GRIDSIZE)) % SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        if len(self.positions) > 2 and new in self.positions[2:]:
            self.reset()
        else:
            self.positions.insert(0, new)
            if len(self.positions) > self.length:
                self.positions.pop()

    def reset(self):
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [((SCREEN_WIDTH / 2), (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2))]
        self.direction = random.choice([UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT])

    def draw(self, surface):
        for p in self.positions:
            r = pygame.Rect((p[0], p[1]), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, r)
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r, 1)

    def handle_keys(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.turn(UP)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.turn(DOWN)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.turn(LEFT)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.turn(RIGHT)


class food(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = (0, 0)
        self.color = (223, 163, 49)
        self.randomize_position()

    def randomize_position(self):
        self.position = (random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH - 1) * GRIDSIZE, random.randint(0, GRID_HEIGHT - 1) * GRIDSIZE)

    def draw(self, surface):
        r = pygame.Rect((self.position[0], self.position[1]), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, r)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r, 1)


def drawGrid(surface):
    for y in range(0, int(GRID_HEIGHT)):
        for x in range(0, int(GRID_WIDTH)):
            if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
                r = pygame.Rect((x * GRIDSIZE, y * GRIDSIZE), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r)
            else:
                rr = pygame.Rect((x * GRIDSIZE, y * GRIDSIZE), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (84, 194, 205), rr)


SCREEN_WIDTH = 400
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

GRIDSIZE = 20
GRID_WIDTH = SCREEN_HEIGHT / GRIDSIZE
GRID_HEIGHT = SCREEN_WIDTH / GRIDSIZE

UP = (0, -1)
DOWN = (0, 1)
LEFT = (-1, 0)
RIGHT = (1, 0)


def main():
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), 0, 32)

    surface = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    surface = surface.convert()
    drawGrid(surface)

    snake1 = snake()
    food1 = food()

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 16)

    score = 0
    while True:
        clock.tick(10)
        snake1.handle_keys()
        drawGrid(surface)
        snake1.move()
        if snake1.get_head_position() == food1.position:
            snake1.length += 1
            score += 1
            food.randomize_position()
        snake1.draw(surface)
        food1.draw(surface)
        screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
        text = myfont.render("Score {0}".format(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (5, 10))
        pygame.display.update()


main()
```

Comment: Typo: It should be `food1.randomize_position()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a typo. It has to be `food1` rather than `food`:

<s>`food.randomize_position()`</s>

```py
food1.randomize_position()
```